# Cannot access org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver Selenide + TestContainers

Tags: selenium, selenide, testcontainers

I am trying to use Selenide `5.0.0` with TestContainers `1.9.1`

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'com.codeborne:selenide:5.0.0'
    testCompile 'org.testcontainers:selenium:1.9.1'
}
```

Apparently, these versions are incompatible, cause when I run my test I get:

```
java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver class file for org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver
enter code here
```

Everything works fine with selenide `4.12.3`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add it to maven pom dependencies, for example when using java:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
 </dependency>
```